# Why Laravel View::make returns empty string without error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have code :

```
$text = View::make('emails.order');
```

And View::make returns empty string. In emails.order.blade.php file is email generated from mjml file. I don't see point of pasting 1000 lines file here, I rather want to find out why View::make can return empty string without error ?

EDITED:

I don't have problem with path because When I put small text in file, e.g. "test", View::make returns "test", but for large file it returns empty string without error...

Error log is empty...

Comment: You shouldn't use a dot in a view name other than to separate the view name from the extensions. Dot resolves to directory spearators.

Comment: It is not problem with view loading, when I put small text in file, e.g. "test" file is loaded...

Comment: Try to load another view in order to tell if the error its in your order view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem appears because I boot vagrant on win host machine with type: "nfs" option. When I boot vagrant without "nfs" option problem does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include `.blade.php` to the name of the view. So, this:

```
View::make('emails.order');
```

will render view file which is called `resources/views/emails/order.blade.php`

Comment: yes, it is mistake when I copied text because variable is in my code....But this is not problem

Comment: You can see `storage/logs/laravel.log` file for the errors.

Comment: laravel.log is empty

Answer (score 0):

Another possible source for this error is an unclosed comment in php-directives.

e.g. if you start your view with phpdoc-comments for type-hinting:

```
@php
/**
 * @var /Example/DataObject $data
/*
@endphp
```

note the "typo" (`/*` instead of `/*`); this will propagate to the view and the whole view will just be a giant comment and therefore return an empty string.